# BigQuery SQL: percent with 2 decimal places

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery standard SQL, I need to present a result of division as **percentage with 2 decimal places, e.g. 21.23%**.
The only way I've been able to achieve this is by the doing the following:

1. `ROUND` the result to 2 decimal places
2. `CAST` it as a string
3. `FORMAT` to add the percent character

`FORMAT('%s%%', CAST(ROUND((val_1 / val_2) * 100, 2) AS STRING))`

It feels like a workaround...

**Is there a proper way of doing it?** 
Primarily, I'd like to keep the output as a float, not a string.

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach seems like the best way I can think of - generally one would not format a percentage in a database - could you not connect your data to a report and format it there?

Comment: You're right, that probably is the best solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach will work. However, I would advise you to create a [TEMP FUNCTION](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting). In case you are going to use it a couple of times, it will make your code look better and easier to read.

The syntax would be as follows:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION NUMFORMAT(number FLOAT64) AS (
  CONCAT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(cast(number as string), r'\d*\.\d{2}'), ' %')
);
SELECT 
  NUMFORMAT(888888.999), 
  NUMFORMAT(123456.99),
  NUMFORMAT(74185.009),
  NUMFORMAT(-10.789)
```

Notice that I am assuming the data you want to format as percentiles is a *FLOAT64*. Although, if it is not a *FLOAT64* you can change that in the function. And the output is:

[image]

If your percentiles are too high, you may also want to format the integer part of the number. The syntax would be as follows:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION NUMFORMAT(number FLOAT64) AS (
  #CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(FORMAT("%'.2f", number), r'([\d,]+).(\d+)', r'\1=\2'), ',', '.'), '=', ','),'%')
  #CONCAT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(cast(number as string), r'\d*\.\d{2}'), ' %')
  CONCAT(format("%'.2f", cast(REGEXP_EXTRACT(cast(number as string), r'\d*\.\d{2}') as float64)), '%')
  );
SELECT 
  NUMFORMAT(888888.999), 
  NUMFORMAT(123456.99),
  NUMFORMAT(74185.009),
  NUMFORMAT(-10.789)
```

The output would be:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't [`round()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#round) do what you want?

```
SELECT ROUND((val_1 / val_2), 2)
```

Comment: it doesn't when you want to concatenate the number with the '%' character.

Comment: @florian . . . The percent sign seems superfluous to me.  But then again, I would prefer ratios between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

as @nick winridge pointed out, there's an issue with less than 2 non-zero decimal places. This is a little hack that I added to fix that..

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION NUMFORMAT(number FLOAT64) AS (
  CONCAT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(cast(((number + 0.000001) as string), r'\d*\.\d{2}'), ' %')
);
```

Comment: This is a good solution but you have three left brackets after "cast", which means the code fails - you only need two.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old post but alexandre moraes's answer won't work if there aren't non-zeros beyond the 2nd decimal place in the argument passed to the function.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION NUMFORMAT(number FLOAT64) AS (
  CONCAT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(cast(number as string), r'\d*\.\d{2}'), ' %')
);
SELECT 
  NUMFORMAT(33.33212121), 
  NUMFORMAT(100.00000),
  NUMFORMAT(100.00),
  NUMFORMAT(100),
  NUMFORMAT(100.00111)
```

gives result:
null values if less than 2 non-zero decimal places.
[image]